# divide different columns of dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns, divide

I have a dataframe with multiple columns

```
     0    1    2    3
2    1    2    2  155
3    1   92    2  145
4    1   87    2  123
5    1   85    2  146
6    1   79    3  138
```

I want to crease a new df with the result of deviding col 0/col1, col2/col3...and so on
Thanks for the help!

Comment: must the last column be divided by the first one?

Comment: the first columns [0] has to be devided by the second [1] the third [2] by the forth [3] ...and like that as many columns I have

Comment: and what about the last one? I mean, the resulting dataframe will have one column less?

Comment: the resulting dataframe will have half the amount of columns the original dataframe had. because I want the division to take place only on groups of 2 I dont want column [1] to be divided by colum [2], only [0]/[1] , [2]/[3], [4]/[5]....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
df1 = df[df.columns[::2]]
df2 = df[df.columns[1::2]]
df2.columns = df1.columns
df1/df2
          0         2
2  0.500000  0.012903
3  0.010870  0.013793
4  0.011494  0.016260
5  0.011765  0.013699
6  0.012658  0.021739
```

Comment: this will work..now im having issues with the fact that my values seem to be str and not int unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'. Im trying data=int(df_data) before the lines you wrote but it doesnt seem to do the trick...any suggestion?

Comment: @Iva if your dataframe has numeric values only you can do `df = df.astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

#original dataframe
org_df = pd.DataFrame({'0': [1,1,1,1,1], '1':[2,92, 87, 85, 79], '2':[2,2,2,2,2], '3': [155,145,123,146,138]}, index = [2,3,4,5,6])

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1'] = org_df['0']/org_df['1']
df['col2'] = org_df['2']/org_df['3']

print(df)
```

Comment: this is an option, however I have hundreds of columns and I wanted to automate it with a loop

Comment: You didn't mention it initially